# page with 2 vertical sections in mobile

Tags: gui-design, responsive-design

I have a wizard which contains 2 sections.
For desktop, the 2 column layout works well, but for mobile, the experience is not very user friendly. Any ideas on how I can improve this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if is too difficult implement this in your context, but here is an option.

[image]

Comment: I think this is much cleaner for desktop too, personally I don't like the alternating image/text directions - forces you to move your focus when reading.

Comment: this will be easy to implement. The layout grid can be setup to arrange the content this way after a particular breakpoint.